# What is _ZStL8__ioinit symbol is for in a c++ symbol table?

Tags: c++, symbols, nm

When I use `nm` command to extract the symbol of my executable, I see there are many symbols of the type `b` (that is for BSS) as `_ZStL8__ioinit`. Also, on using `c++filt` to see the demangled symbol, I get the following:

`~ c++filt _ZStL8__ioinit
~ std::__ioinit`

What are these symbols for? and Why my code has more than one?

Any lead would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: IIRC they're the ones from std::Init, e.g. initializes `iostream` library.

Comment: Internal implementation details of your C++ library. Nothing more, nothing else.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-api-4.5/a00901.html

Comment: What is the explanation of more than one `std::__ioinit` symbol?

Comment: Ask one question per post. Ask after thorough research. Note I don't think the question a good fit for the site.

Comment: Aren't both questions seem closely related to you? Plus you don't ask a question knowing how big or small would be the answer.

Comment: Related is not the same. Putting everything related into the same question makes it impossible to find what you're looking for.